# Spring MVC: using Jackson for incoming requests and FlexJSON Serializer for responses

Tags: json, spring-mvc, serialization, jackson, flexjson

I'd like to use Jackson to deserialize JSON strings from client requests to Java objects and use FlexJson to serialize Java objects to response.

In the nutshell the issue is: how to setup the Spring to use Jackson ONLY for request handling and not for response?

In servlet-context.xml I have:

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="messageConverters">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
</beans:bean>
```

And in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "settings")
public @ResponseBody String getSomeData(@RequestBody UserData userData) { 
    // userData is automatically deserialized by Jackson   
    MyView viewForClient = new MyView(userData);        

    return new JSONSerializer().include(MyView.SERILIZABLE_FIELDS).exclude("*", "*.class").serialize(viewForClient); // here I don't want Jackson to handle the response        
}
```

But this way Jackson also converts to JSON the response already converted by FlexJSON that I don't want.

Is there any solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to build a custom `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` bean where you plug in Jackson for the serialization methods, and FlexJSON for the deserialization methods.

Comment: Yes, that could work, however I have already found the better way. Spring has a number of default HttpRequestConverter instances pre-enabled and uses convenient one depending on the request Content-Type. So in my case it was just enough to add Jackson dependency in the project and send request with application/json content type. That causes Jackson to read data from the request body and deserialize to object. And response is not processed by Jackson.

Comment: same here, just added the jackson2 jars, and you get to do things like (at)RequestBody YourDomainObject yourDomainObject and jackson does its thing. I imagine if you tried to return yourDomainObject, the reverse would kick into effect with (at)ResponseBody, but if you're using flexjson, then you're most likely returning a ResponseEntity<String> which doesnt seem to trigger any jackson processing